# How to specify content type produced by a handler in Spring Messaging?

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-messaging, spring-websocket

I'm experimenting with Spring 4 WebSocket STOMP application. Is there a way to explicitly specify content type of the returned message produced by a handler? By default the handler below produces `application/json` and processed by corresponding message converter.

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @MessageMapping("/products/{id}")
    public String getProduct(@DestinationVariable int id) {
        return getProductById(id);
    }

}
```

I'm looking for something like `@RequestMapping(produces = "text/xml")` in Spring MVC.

**UPDATE** (reply to [Rossen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21414446/617900)):

Ideally I would like to be able to return both formats depending on what the user asks for. But if I have to choose, I would say XML and almost never JSON (XML is just an example, we use binary format). I went the second way you suggested - configuring custom converters *instead of* the default ones.

1. I have implemented custom `MessageConverter` extending `AbstractMessageConverter`. In the constructor I've registered appropriate supported MimeType.
2. Then I've registered my custom converter by overriding `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`'s `configureMessageConverters`, and return `false` from the method to not add default converters.
3. As soon as my controller returns the value I get NPE in `SendToMethodReturnValueHandler`'s `postProcessMessage`. This happens because `CompositeMessageConverter` contains only a single converter - my custom one. But my converter fails `AbstractMessageConverter`'s `supportsMimeType` check and `AbstractMessageConverter`'s `toMessage` returns `null`. This `null` causes the exception in `postProcessMessage`.

As the workaround I can register additional default MimeType `application/json` for my custom converter. But it looks like too dirty to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like the produces condition. The only way to do this right now is to inject `SimpMessagingTemplate` and then use the convertAndSend method variation that takes a `MessagePostProcessor`. It could be made simpler. What's your use case? Are you using JSON primarily and need to use XML in a few places? Or do you need to use XML primarily? If it is the latter you can simply configure the converters to use instead of the default ones.

Comment: Please, see my reply above.

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug. Could you open a ticket in JIRA with stack trace details? Why does supportsMimeType return false by the way given that you have configured supported mime types and it returns true if no content-type header is found. Is there no match for it then, and if so should there be another converter registered perhaps?

Comment: Will file an issue. `supportsMimeType` returns `false` because `getMimeType(headers)` returns `"application/json"` even if `headers == null`. But it doesn't match any of my converter's registered MimeTypes. Not sure why `getMimeType(headers)` returns JSON for `null`, will be able to check it later today.

Comment: I guess I see why it happens: `AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration` finds `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` on the classpath and sets `jackson2Present` to `true`. It makes `getContentTypeResolver()` method to set `"application/json"` as default MimeType. In turn `DefaultContentTypeResolver#resolve` returns this default MimeType if `headers==null`

Comment: Thanks I've updated the issue. Probably a better solution before it's fixed is to set the default content type to something other than application/json (or not set it at all). See my comments under the filed issue. Lets continue there.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you can change the headers changing the Message converter.
For example:

```
SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
..
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
or
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
```

when you use StringMessageConverter then the Java client add an content-type header.

```
GenericMessage [payload=byte[33], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={destination=[/app/chatchannel], content-type=[text/plain;charset=UTF-8], content-length=[33]}, simpSessionAttributes={ip=/127.0.0.1:59629}, simpHeartbeat=[J@147a2bf, contentType=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, lookupDestination=/chatchannel, simpSessionId=79431feb8b5f4a9497492ccc64f8965f, simpDestination=/app/chatchannel}]
```

But if you use SimpleMessageConverter, the content-type header is not add.

this is a clue about what you want to do?

Check this question, I put some code that could help you:

[How configure the Spring Sockjs Java Client message converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024998/how-configure-the-spring-sockjs-java-client-message-converters)