# How configure the Spring Sockjs Java Client message converters

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs, spring-messaging

I have one SockJS Java client that use STOMP. Is base on this https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/load/StompWebSocketLoadTestClient.java.

My code:

```
package mx.intercommunication.websocket.stompclient;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.StringMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.Transport;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport;
public class StompClient {
    public StompClient(){
        cliente();
    }
    public void cliente() {
        String host = "localhost";

        int port = 8080;
        String stompUrl = "ws://{host}:{port}/Server/chat";

        StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();

        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(2);

        /*
         * The WebSocketTransport can be configured with:
         *      + StandardWebSocketClient in a JSR-356 runtime
         *      + JettyWebSocketClient using the Jetty 9+ native WebSocket API
         *      + Any implementation of Spring’s WebSocketClient
         */
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(webSocketClient));

        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);


        //Configure a scheduler to use for heartbeats and for receipt tracking. 
        //stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        //stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[] {0, 0});

        /*
         * Set the MessageConverter to use to convert the payload of incoming and
         *  outgoing messages to and from byte[] based on object type and the "content-type" header. 
         * By default, SimpleMessageConverter is configured.
         */
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());


        ProducerStompSessionHandler producer = new ProducerStompSessionHandler();


         /*
         * Connect to the given WebSocket URL and notify the given
         *   org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler when connected on
         *   the STOMP level after the CONNECTED frame is received.
         *   
         *   Parameters:
         *          url the url to connect to
         *          handler the session handler
         *          uriVars URI variables to expand into the URL
         *   Returns:
         *          ListenableFuture for access to the session when ready for use
         * 
         */
        stompClient.connect(stompUrl, producer, host, port);


    }

    private static class ProducerStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

        //private final AtomicReference<Throwable> failure;

        private StompSession session;


        @Override
        public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
            this.session =  session;


            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Json m = Json.object()
                .set("from", "cliente1")
                .set("text", "KIKO");

            String message = m.toString();

            //byte messageByteArr[] = message.getBytes();

            /*
             * Send a message to the specified destination, converting the payload to a
             *  byte[] with the help of a MessageConverter.
             *  
             * Parameters:
             *      destination:     the destination to send a message to
             *      payload:        the message payload
             * Returns:
             *      a Receiptable for tracking receipts
             */
            try {
                session.send("/app/chatchannel", message);
                //session.send("/app/chatchannel", messageByteArr);

                System.out.println("Sending message HELLO: "+message);

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Message sending failed: "+t);

                //logger.error("Message sending failed at " + i, t);
                //failure.set(t);
            }


        }

        /**
         * This implementation returns String as the expected payload type
         * for STOMP ERROR frames.
         */
        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            Exception ex = new Exception(headers.toString());
            System.out.println("STOMP ERROR frame: "+ex);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers,
                byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {

            System.out.println("Handling exception: "+exception);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {

            System.out.println("Transport error: "+exception);
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            //return "ConsumerStompSessionHandler[messageCount=" + this.messageCount + "]";
            return "ConsumerStompSessionHandler to String....";
        }

    }
}
```

Please check that when I configure `stompClient` as:

```
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
```

and I send a message:

```
session.send("/app/chatchannel", message);
```

where message is a String class object, the server side thrown the next conversion error:

```
08:51:06,746 ERROR [org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler] (clientInboundChannel-4) Unhandled exception from message handler method: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [org.gasmart.websocket.Message] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[33], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={destination=[/app/chatchannel], content-type=[text/plain;charset=UTF-8], content-length=[33]}, simpSessionAttributes={ip=/127.0.0.1:59629}, simpHeartbeat=[J@147a2bf, contentType=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, lookupDestination=/chatchannel, simpSessionId=79431feb8b5f4a9497492ccc64f8965f, simpDestination=/app/chatchannel}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:124)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:502)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:497)
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:87)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:461)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:399)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Observe the error:

MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [org.gasmart.websocket.Message] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[33], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={destination=[/app/chatchannel], **content-type=[text/plain;charset=UTF-8]**, content-length=[33]}, simpSessionAttributes={ip=/127.0.0.1:59629}, simpHeartbeat=[J@147a2bf, contentType=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, lookupDestination=/chatchannel, simpSessionId=79431feb8b5f4a9497492ccc64f8965f, simpDestination=/app/chatchannel}]

see that the **content-type** header is created by the SockJS Java client.

If I configure `stompClient` as:

```
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
```

and I send a message:

```
...
String message = m.toString();      
byte messageByteArr[] = message.getBytes();
session.send("/app/chatchannel", message);
```

where message is a byte array , the server don't thrown error.
But I need to be converting all the String to byte array before to send.
I want understand why the Server can convert the same JSON object send with a 
SimpleMessageConverter and one send with StringMessageConverter.

I do a comparative of a JSON sended from a JavaScript client and the Java client. Both send the same JSON message. Then I implemented a ChannelInterceptor to print the messages received before the message to be send to the corresponding controller:

```
public class WebSocketTraceChannelInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public void afterSendCompletion(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent, Exception ex) {
         String payload = new String((byte[]) message.getPayload());
                                System.out.println("WebSocketTraceChannelInterceptor::afterSendCompletion!!    payload: "+payload);
    }   
}
```

The corresponding server controller is:

```
@MessageMapping("/chatchannel")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public OutputMessage send(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor ha,@Payload Message message) throws Exception {
.....
}
```

The Java output:

```
message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[33], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={destination=[/app/chatchannel], **content-type=[text/plain;charset=UTF-8]**, content-length=[33]}, simpSessionAttributes={ip=/127.0.0.1:59629}, simpHeartbeat=[J@147a2bf, contentType=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, simpSessionId=79431feb8b5f4a9497492ccc64f8965f, simpDestination=/app/chatchannel}]
```

while the JavaScript:  SockJS + Stomp.js:

```
message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[33], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={destination=[/app/chatchannel], content-length=[33]}, simpSessionAttributes={ip=/127.0.0.1:57890}, simpHeartbeat=[J@d154f0, simpSessionId=innyvfme, simpDestination=/app/chatchannel}]
```

Observe the difference:  **content-type=[text/plain;charset=UTF-8]**

There are more converters in Spring messaging:

[image: Spring Messaging converters]

You can observe the SimpleMessageConverter and the StringMessageConverter in this package.  But there are ByteArrayMessageConverter, CompositeMessageConverter, SmartMessageConverter, etc.
How work this converters?

If I want sent String from the Java Client what converter I need ?

Why the server can convert the JSON message {"from":"cliente1","text":"KIKO"} when is send from a JScript client but not whe send form the Java client?

Answer (score 2):

try to create a Bean like

```
public class SimpleBean{
private String from;
private String text; 
public String getFrom(){return from;}
public String getText(){return text:}
//other methods like setters here... 
}
```

then set the messageConverter in this way

```
            MappingJackson2MessageConverter m = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
            stompClient.setMessageConverter(m);
```

I have not seen any invocation of the "subscribe" method for your client in the method "afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders)"

```
    session.subscribe(subscribeMethod, new StompFrameHandler() {
//.. overriding for public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {} and
// public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {} here
});
```

Than call for the "send" method, using an instance for the SimpleBean defined just before:

```
SimpleBean sb=new SimpleBean();
sb.setFrom("cliente1");
sb.setText("KIKO");
session.send("/app/chatchannel", sb);
```

This should help.